# Disambiguate the [amazon] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [amazon](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) is used to refer to several unrelated products from Amazon: their sales platform, their VM hosting, etc. We need to disambiguate it.

What tags should we create? Preferably aligning with other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: As it currently holds but 9 question, we can take our time finding a well-suited solution ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest leaving [amazon](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) as the Amazon store tag, and [amazon-web-services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) for AWS. This is how Stack Overflow does it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think we should leave it as it is. This tag is not over populated and does not need any more separation.